# How to use ffmpeg headphone filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to use [headphone filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#headphone) using [surround filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#surround) but cant. How do I fix it?

```
ffmpeg -i 10.mp4 -filter_complex "surround,channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1[FL][FR][FC][LFE][BL][BR],[0:a][FL][FR][FC][LFE][BL][BR]headphone=FL|FR|FC|LFE|BL|BR"  -y -t 100 hoge.wav

ffmpeg version N-86447-gfeb13ae Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 63.100 / 55. 63.100
  libavcodec     57. 98.100 / 57. 98.100
  libavformat    57. 73.100 / 57. 73.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 92.100 /  6. 92.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '10.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isom
    creation_time   : 2016-12-06T06:06:38.000000Z
    copyright       : 
    copyright-eng   : 
  Duration: 00:23:40.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 833 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 704 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 48k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> surround
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> headphone:in0
  headphone -> Stream #0:0 (pcm_s16le)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, wav, to 'hoge.wav':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isom
    copyright-eng   : 
    ICOP            : 
    ISFT            : Lavf57.73.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.98.100 pcm_s16le
[Parsed_headphone_2 @ 000000000030ee20] Too big length of IRs: 6144 > 4096.
Error while filtering: Invalid argument
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not feed surround channels to headphone filter. IR files can be downloaded from https://www.york.ac.uk/sadie-project/binaural.html

Then use multichannel audio with headphone filter like its mentioned in documentation: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-headphone

Comment: I understand how to use it. Thank you for the reply :)